# AJAX Post Request not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, post

I have a  tag in my jsp as follows:

```
<a href="<%=rest.getString(5)%>" onclick="javascript: generateLog(<%=id%>,<%=id2%>,<%=id3%>);">xxxx</a>
```

The function generateLog is defined as follows:

```
function generateLog(id1,id2,id3) {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "generateLog.jsp",
           data: "id1=" + id1+"&id2="+id2+"&id3="+id3,
           cache: false,
           async: true
         });

}
```

In the generateLog.jsp, code is written to insert the click ids into a table. It works fine in IE, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome but does not work in Apple Safari.

It seems the page navigates to href page location before the post request is completed. How can I make it work in Safari? Please help.

Comment: Don't forget to explain what "does not work" means - does this code generate an error message? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

make `async : !$.browser.safari`